# Android: GPS_PROVIDER is triggering several location changes to hundred meters far, even while device is not moving (stationary)

Tags: android, gps, location

I start monitoring GPS_PROVIDER by using the folowing code:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGPS)
```

When it returns me a location with a good precision (50 meters or less), I plot it into a map and then I stop the locationmanger updates, rescheduling it to start monitoring updates again 2 minutes later.

There are a lot of readings that are perfectly fine, pointing to exact location I am. But sometimes it seems to get 'crazy' and starts to give me wrong locations, but all readings have a good precision (50 meters or less). The strange thing is that my DEVICE IS STILL STANDING sitting on my desktop all the time!

I've tested it with 3 different devices (including tablets and phones) and all of them got same behavior in sometime.

Here's a map showing all locations returned by LocationListener. The green one is the "good one". Red circles show the locations precision (not larger than 50 meters).

Does anybody have any ideia why it is happening?

[image: map]

Comment: have you gotten any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

in your location provider, you can do an accuracy check to determine if it meets your standards:

In your location Listener you can create these two static longs:

```
 private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 ; // 1 sec
```

and say:

```
public Location getLocation() {
        try {

            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                    String gpsStatus;
                    String netStatus;

                    if(isGPSEnabled){
                        gpsStatus = "Enabled";
                    }else{
                        gpsStatus = "Disabled";
                    }

                    if(isNetworkEnabled){
                        netStatus = "Enabled";
                    }else{
                       netStatus = "Disabled";
                    }
                    _parent.showSettingsAlert("To participate inDrop you need your location enabled." +
                            "\n\nWe recommend enabling both GPS Satelite and mobile Network Location for improved accuracy." +
                            "\n\nYour Current Settings" +
                            "\nGPS: "+gpsStatus+
                            "\nNetwork: "+netStatus);


                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;

                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                   // Toast.makeText(mContext, "GPS TRACK USING NETWORK",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        netLocation = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (netLocation != null) {
                            net_latitude = netLocation.getLatitude();
                            net_longitude = netLocation.getLongitude();
                            net_rating =netLocation.getAccuracy();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                sat_latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                sat_longitude = location.getLongitude();

                                sat_rating =location.getAccuracy();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }
```

something like:

```
 @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            //Log.v("location ","location updated by:"+location.getProvider());
             if (location != null) {

                 accuracy = location.getAccuracy();
                 time = location.getTime();
                if ((time > minTime && accuracy <= bestAccuracy && accuracy !=0)) {
                  bestResult = location;
                  bestAccuracy = accuracy;
                  bestTime = time;
                }
                else if (time < minTime && 
                         bestAccuracy == Float.MAX_VALUE && time > bestTime){
                  bestResult = location;
                  bestTime = time;
                }
              }
             if(bestResult!=null){
                 _parent.update(bestResult);

             }else{
                 _parent.update(location);

             }
        }
```

**the update method**

```
public void update(Location local) {

        if (local.getAccuracy() < 2000 && local.getAccuracy() != 0) {

            updates++;
            if (updates >= 1) {
                if (updates == 1) {
                    _startingLocal = local;
                    try {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }

                _latestLocal = local;
                updateMap(local.getBearing());

                if (_latestLocal.getAccuracy() <= 10) {
                    currentAccuracy = 1;

                } else if (_latestLocal.getAccuracy() <= 15) {

                    currentAccuracy = 2;
                } else {

                    currentAccuracy = 3;
                }

                if (lastAccuracy > 0) {
                    if (lastAccuracy != currentAccuracy) {
                        if (currentAccuracy > lastAccuracy) {

                        } else {

                        }
                    }
                } else if (currentAccuracy > 0) {
                    lastAccuracy = currentAccuracy;
                }
                if (mListener != null && _latestLocal != null) {
                    try {
                        mListener.onLocationChanged(_latestLocal);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Normalizing Location Data "
                            + updates + " of 3.");
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

            }

        } else if (updates == 0) {
            try {
                progressDialog.setMessage("Aquiring Location Service.");
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: I already do that! I just consider a location valid if it has accuracy and if it's less than 50 meters.

Comment: unfortunately, so many things can effect the accuracy of the gps.  cloud coverage etc.

Comment: @eric : you're saying that it's perfectly normal that kind of 'variation'? Is there any way to reduce the error?

Comment: Turning on AGPS might help.  Or go outside.

Comment: im editing my answer to include the _parent.update(location) method.  i get fairly good results with this.. and note that i use wifi and satelites

Comment: @erik: cloud coverage does not affect gps (according to this: http://gpstracklog.com/2005/09/does_cloud_cove.html

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede: AGPS is active and I'm outside while testing!

Comment: Ok but my point is that all sorts of things can... For satellite to work accurately you need a clear line of site.. and of course no space invaders

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Fused Location Provider.  GPS can vary a lot, especially indoors.  Fused location provider also uses sensors (accelerometer..) to improve location.  If the device has not been accelerated, the position has not changed.

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html